# Is JS enabled when testing with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, testing

I'm using Laravel tests to test a form.

I'm trying to use `$this->select('value','selectName')` to set an option on a select, but this selects is populated on the page with the following script:

```
<script>
    for(var i = 1940; i < 2020; i++){
         document.write('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
</script>
```

But when I run the test, I get :

```
InvalidArgumentException: Input "year" cannot take "1992" as a value (possible values: ).
```

When I just make the options with html tags however, everything runs fine, so I'm guessing JS is not enabled or runs after the parsing.

Is this expected behaviour? What can I do to test it with JS enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JavaScript is a client side scripting language, basically executed in the browser at runtime it cannot be used by Laravel in tests. That being said there are some extensions/drivers for laravel that can enable this feature. You can check out Selenium.

Here is a great place to read on this topic:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/has-anyone-tried-laravel-integrated-package-in-laravel-52

Comment: Well, apparently it does not. So this is the answer. Thanks for the link.